# mongoDB takes 1.04 sec for a simple find request with node,js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm on windows,and localhost
here is my code:

```
 MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            MonCallback("ERROR mongo: " + err);
        }
        var dbo = db.db(databaseName);


        dbo.collection(collection).find(optionMon).explain(function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                MonCallback("ERROR mongo: " + err);
            }
            MonCallback(res);
            db.close();
        });

    });
```

and

```
optionMon ={
    access_tokens:{
                    login_access_token: req_data.cookie.login_access_token
                }
    }
```

and I have only 3 records. but it takes 1 second to run.
Q2: I  call `MongoClient.connect()` for every database requests. I think it has a problem. it is ok?

Comment: You should call MongoClient.connect() once and use what it gives you back for all future queries, the connection is what's taking the time up, you only need to do it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call MongoClient.connect() once and use what it gives you back for all future queries, the connection is what's taking the time up, you only need to do it once. – Prodigle.

this work. Thanks Prodigle.